# How to give icon class in f.submit in rails4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view

Hi I want to give this in my rails code

```
<div class="col s12 center-align">
    <button name="action" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray">Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i> </button>
</div>
```

So for this I had written this in my rails form

```
<div class="col s12 center-align">
   <%= f.submit 'Submit<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i> ', :class => 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray'%>
 </div>
```

So with the above rails form code its giving this type of html

```
<div class="col s12 center-align">
    <i class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray waves-input-wrapper" style=""><input type="submit" class="waves-button-input" value="Submit&lt;i class=&quot;mdi-content-send right&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; " name="commit"></i>
 </div>
```

Please guide me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use button_tag instead:

```
<div class="col s12 center-align">
   <%= button_tag( :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray") do %>
      Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: its showing css correctly but does not redirect to my form action

Comment: Did you add this inside the form tags?

Answer (score 1):

you can format the content in your button using

```
<%= f.submit class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray' do %>
  Submit
  <%= content_tag 'i', '', class: 'mdi-content-send right' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: FormBuilder submit does not accept block arguments, only button_tag does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I answered this question in the beginning days of learning rails. @FilipeGorgesReuwsaat

Answer (score -1):

Hi solved this just by copying simply

```
<div class="col s12 center-align">
    <button name="action" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray">Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i> </button>
</div>
```

this in my form and my form is also working correctly.